# Monopole magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-monopoles

Let's say I have a set of weak refrigerator magnets. I place these magnets in a complete sphere 1 foot in diameter, with all their south poles facing inward and their north poles facing outward. Furthermore, I isolate the magnetic fields from each other using something like mumetal. The mumetal casings cover the inward south pole, and the sides of the magnet. In between each mumetal wrapper is a layer of another material.

Would such a system exhibit any magnetic properties? I know this has been asked before in slightly different forms, but the difference here is a matter of scale, and insulating each individual magnetic field from the other fields.

Comment: I think if you reworded it correctly it could be no longer a duplicate